# Video Embed Field module - how do I add attribute 'id' to the embed youtube iframe?

Tags: 7, entities, files, nodes

The question is related to DRUPAL modules name is '[Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field)' module.

The default output of this module generated the Youtube iframe embed as set in the config by Administrator. But...
[image: There is no ID attribute that is generated by the module core]
The iframe's attribute can be set only for width, height, src but no 'id'. What I want is to hard-code into the module core and add 'id' attribute into the iframe, so every time I setup the embed field I have an id on the iframe.

I cannot find the place where the module core generate the iframe attribute...

Regards,